# Vue, wait data is assign to run a function

Tags: vue.js

I have a method in my `Vue` instance that do the following:

```
submitForm(confirmation) {
            //set price confirmation
            this.price_confirmation = confirmation

            //proceed
            var form = this.getForm()
}
```

Price confirmation is the v-model of an input.

Then the method getForm serialize (with jquery) the form. The thing is that my form is being serialized before `this.price_confirmation = confirmation` is run.

How can I run `this.getForm()` after `Vue` assign the data?

Comment: Try `this.$nextTick(function() { var form = this.getForm(); });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to use the `nextTick` method to wait until the next update cycle:

```
submitForm(confirmation) {
    //set price confirmation
    this.price_confirmation = confirmation

    //proceed
    this.$nextTick(() => {
        var form = this.getForm();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you've shared, it's not clear how the `confirmation` is set in your component and at what point the `submitForm` is called. `submitForm`  method seems to be correct, and should work correctly (i.e. `this.getForm()` is called after `this.price_confirmation` is set). What you could do is, look where the `confirmation` variable is set and add an async function to it. e.g:

```
async confirmation() {
    await getConfirmations();
}
```

If you need more help please share the relevant code from your component.